# Why is the baby formula not yet spoiled after a year in The Walking Dead?

Tags: the-walking-dead

In season 3 we see that Glenn and Maggie are sent off to get baby formula for Rick's daughter. And surprisingly the baby formula is still good for consumption, even though I believe it was not stored properly. I think these formulas are highly perishable and have an expiration date.

Comment: I don't recall if it was shown whether the formula was powdered or liquid, but powdered formula can easily last a year if the can remains sealed.

Comment: Food products don't become useless immediately after the expiration date.  Expiration dates tend to err on the side of caution.  In an emergency situation without other alternatives, "expired" food may well be enough.

Answer (score 13):

It's powdered formula. You mix it with water. Unless you do, it will last for a long time.

Comment: almost anything will last for years under most any conditions (maybe even decades), as long as the can or other airtight packaging it's contained in isn't damaged and the product was properly treated before packaging (usually sterilisation and packaging under a nitrogen overpressure).

Answer (score 7):

From a LiveStrong article on the subject:

> Most formula containers are good for at least a year.

Read more: http://www.livestrong.com/article/219642-how-long-is-baby-formula-good/#ixzz2OZT4Qkh4

Answer (score 4):

As long as it is prepared (pasteurized and vacuumed up in a sterile container) the formula wouldn’t go bad for a long, long time.
In '93 i have eaten ration packages that had labels from the '60s and'70s on them.

Answer (score -1):

Dry formula will last for years and years in the right environment. (Cool dry place). GA is NOT a cool dry place.

Medications are the same way. I wouldn't hesitate to take a 3 year old Advil from my cabinet. Would you, anyone?